# pbf files in android application

Tags: android, navigation, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I'm developing an offline routing application for android.

I'm working with osmdroid library. and I downloaded the pbf file for the region where I want to do the offline navigation but I'm not sure how to be able to convert the binary representation of the maps in the pbf files into a normal text.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use the [PBF format](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Pbf), at the moment the [OSM XML format](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_XML) is still widely in use. But if you do, then you will probably have to implement a PBF reader for Android. See [osmosis](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis) which serves as the reference implementation for PBF and can also convert between those two file formats.

You can take a look at the [Android](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Android) page in the OSM wiki where lots of OSM-related Android application are listed. Maybe there is already an Android application supporting PBF. But most of them will just display tiles and the rather popular OsmAnd uses its own file format instead.

Note that PBF has various advantages compared to XML. It is smaller and  it is faster to read and write than compressed XML. It also supports random access which can become very handy for a routing engine.

Comment: that's why im trying to find a way to use the pfb format bcoz XML is too big for a mobile phone. 

If u got any clue or library that would be useful. 

Thanks mate.

Comment: You shouldn't use a raw PBF file anyway. You can strip a lot of tags which you don't need for routing in order to save space, e.g. buildings, landuse, natural, source, created_by and so on... Besides, I already mentioned a tool to read PBF: osmosis.

Comment: pbf is not efficient in terms of size and speed for routing/navigation, again look into the suggested links and also https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing